# Django: Since it is not strictly MVC, but MTV, what is "view"?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, model, django-views

I'm new to Django and I read two somewhat contradictory things about it. One source says that it is based on MVC (Model-view-controller) style, other argues that it is MTV (Model-template-view). I understand it as MTV. Am I correct in my view? No pun intended.

If it is, I'm still confused by the two notions of "view", since they are different in two contexts.

Django documentaion says:

> A view is a “type” of Web page in your Django application that generally serves a specific function and has a specific template.

To me this sounds like the view is a function-with-template.

Does anyone have a clear understanding of the situation? And a good, the simpler the better, explanation. Maybe some analogies?

Comment: The Django View is the Controller in the way everyone but the developers of Django understand MVC.

Comment: Wooble, ty. I searched for django mvc, but somehow this wasn't in the top 5 results. Not even in the top 10, so I naturally missed it.

Comment: Also, I tried adding an "MTV" tag, but I don't have enough reputation to do that. And it isn't in the system surprisingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting confused by patterns and styles and analogies and acronyms.

Django has a file named `urls.py`, that maps incoming requests to views. A view is a function (or class implementing some methods) of which the return value (a `HTTPResponse`, usually) is sent back to the browser. Often, but not necessarily always, views use templates to make that return value.

Django also has an ORM layer (a mapping between Python classes and database tables), and such classes representing database tables are called "models". Views often need information from the database, and they call functions on the models to get it.

Another core part of Django is the form handling. Views often need to get parameters from the request (like from submitted forms) and they use forms for that.

And that's Django. If that is obviously some acronym pattern to you, feel free to consider it that...

Comment: This eschewing of buzzwords is entirely welcome. =D

Answer (score 0):

Views are the places where we use to write the Business Logic. Business Logic can be written anywhere in the project but it is suggested to write it in the views.
A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a Web response. This response can be the HTML contents of a Web page, or a redirect, or a 404 error, or an XML document, or an image . . . or anything, really. The view itself contains whatever arbitrary logic is necessary to return that response. This code can live anywhere you want, as long as it’s on your Python path. There’s no other requirement–no “magic,” so to speak. For the sake of putting the code somewhere, the convention is to put views in a file called views.py, placed in your project or application directory.
Go through the docs for a much clear idea.

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/#writing-views
```